# How to make Chrome remember all URL's?

Tags: google-chrome

Remembered URL's are a very important part of my productivity, compared to Chrome, Firefox was very well polished in these areas, yet I switched to Chrome for performance reasons

After months or weeks, some URL's I visited seem to disappear from Chrome's suggestions, when I google them for example, they are marked as visited, yet they don't show up to auto-fill at the url-bar - I end up losing a lot of time searching for URL's

I'm hoping there might be an internal feature/switch that enables what I want, or an sqlite modification method that ensures all URL's show up for suggestions, it's also unclear how/why some URL's seem to disappear

Comment: 90 days limit for history.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that info, I've researched possible solutions further, checked the internal flags/settings of chrome, yet I couldn't find any simple solution - I'm guessing a routine that parses the sqlite history db periodically and saves expiring urls might solve the issue